# SQL Server T-Log Shrink

Tags: sql-server

why we have to manually shrink the transaction log file (.ldf), Upon my knowledge Backing up the .ldf file automatically truncates the file and make space for new records, then why sometime we have perform a manual shrink.

I have found out that the simple recovery mode will automatically shrink the logs but not with Full mode, is this the reason?
I need a better explanation on how this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have found out that the simple recovery mode will automatically
> shrink the logs but not with Full mode

Automatic shrinking of log files (and data files) is unrelated to the recovery model. Files will shrink automatically only if the database [AUTO_SHRINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/database-file-operations/considerations-autogrow-autoshrink#considerations-for-auto_shrink) option is turned on. `AUTO_SHRINK` is not generally recommended and should be used judiciously to avoid performance problems. See [Considerations for AUTO_SHRINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/database-file-operations/considerations-autogrow-autoshrink#considerations-for-auto_shrink) in the documentation for details.

A best practice is to size log files to accommodate all activity between log backups. It is appropriate to shrink a log manually only if it grew due to an extraordinary event, such as not running log backups for an extended period.

Separately, automatic log truncation reclaims space within the log file and depends on the recovery model. Below is the explanation from the [transaction log truncation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#Truncation) topic in the doc on when log truncation occurs:

> To avoid running out of space, unless log truncation is delayed for
> some reason, truncation occurs automatically after the following
> events:
>
> - Under the simple recovery model, after a checkpoint.
> - Under the full recovery model or bulk-logged recovery model, if a    checkpoint has occurred since the previous backup, truncation occurs
>   after a log backup (unless it is a copy-only log backup).
> - When you first create a database using the FULL recovery model, the    transaction log will be reused as needed (similar to a SIMPLE
>   recovery database), up until the time you create a full database
>   backup.

Comment: Thanks Dan, for answering, So as per I understood, Truncate and Shrink is two different things, I was seeing them as same.

Comment: Can you check if I understand it right, Say we have a 100MB log file, if it get truncates them the file size will remain the same i.e 100MB only the active parts changes into inactive parts  so it can be reuse for other records, Whereas, In shrinking, the actual 100MB file will get reduce to say 5MB (Physical level)

Comment: @Boogeyman, correct, truncation doesn't change file size whereas shrink reduces physical file size.